# php curl not working properly

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have been trying to get a web content from a link using PHP. I have tried using `file_get_contents()` and curl but both are not working with the link I want. My `curl` code is as follows :

```
function request($url){
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $res = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   return $res;
}
echo request("http://...");
```

This code prints something like "ï»¿"

This code works with sites like Google but doesn't work with the url I want. However, when I try it with the `curl` terminal command, it works from there. What could be the problem ?

Here is the `curl -I` output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Jun 2014 23:47:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=m7fs1ikt47epgoiekg68nnq064; path=/; domain=.sozlukspot.com
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: @meda I checked that one out, didn't help

Comment: @JakeGould added the output to the question. Doesn't seem to be gzipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I reworked your function with a standard set of `curl` options I set for getting content from remote URLs. I believe it should work.

I believe the issue is the site you are trying to connect to refuses connections from web requests that don’t have a proper user agent set, are pure `curl` requests or just have a blank user agent. So setting the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` in `curl` should work. I have it set to a fairly generic `Mozilla/5.0` setting here, but change that to whatever other agent you feel you would need to set that to.

```
function request($url){
    // The actual curl request.
    $curl_timeout = 5;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $curl_timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $res;
}
echo request("http://...");
```

Answer (score 0):

The site you are accessing is returning the BOM marker. This usually indicates that the character encoding is in UNICODE format. Try changing the last line in your function to:

```
return utf8_decode($res);
```